# Access blocked by CORS policy

Tags: docker, cors

I have an Ubuntu machine running two docker nodes. When I try to access nodes from my web based application, installed on the same machine I keep getting the following error :

> web3.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8502/' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Even if my starting command is the following:

```bash
CMD exec ./geth --syncmode 'full' --port 30313 --rpc --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr '0.0.0.0'  --rpcport 8503 --rpcapi  personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner --bootnodes "enode://$bootnodeId@$bootnodeIp:30311" --networkid="1005" --gasprice '1' -unlock $address --password ~/.password --mine
```

so including : `--rpccorsdomain '*'`

Result is the same with google chrome and with Firefox.
Connection with Metamask is working well.

Can anybody help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`Cross-Origin Resource Sharing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is probably not defined right, when REQUESTING because Metamask works fine.

It is likely that you try to access the nodes from a different port (This was at least an issue I had once) otherwise,
I would suggest looking at the HEADERs metamask sends to your nodes and try to figure things out from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, below is the calling function:
var eth_node_url = 'http://localhost:8502'; // TODO: remote URL
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(eth_node_url));
Port is the same as the one used by Metamask.

I am trying to find the Metamask header.

Comment: Did you try [this snippet from the docs?](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3.html#configuration). I think this could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow the solution I am trying to install is this one : https://github.com/etherparty/explorer

Comment: I think the issue is on the eth node side ...  How is it possible to check from container console if the config is correct and which CORS domains are authorise ? Thanks

Comment: Just tried to update the geth version, but still the same problem ...

Comment: Did you try [this](https://github.com/etherparty/explorer/issues/65)? Replacing `--rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000"` with `--http --http.api 'web3,eth,net,debug,personal' --http.corsdomain '*'`. Also the project was last updated 5 years ago, until then a lot has happened, it's probably some api change in the geth node, which is responsible for the incompatibilities. Otherwise I'm basically out of ideas. I don't have the resources to run a geth instance right now so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Another idea is to look for forks with more recent activities, maybe anotherone has come across this issue and already solved it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I need to use a blockchain explorer for a local nodes at the end, which one would you recommend ? I need one that can be installed eseally on a local Virtual Machine already hosting local docker geth nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed at the end by switching to another Linux distrib as host. We tried at the beginning with Lubuntu because we had in our requirements to have something light to be distributed. Moving to a standard Ubuntu client fixed the issue.